# Random Hair Rotation

Tags: particles

I'm trying to scattered crumbs using the hair system.  The problem is that all of the dupli objects are facing the same direction.  Is there a way to randomly rotate each particle (similar to the random size setting)?

Currently I'm achieving the effect by brushing the hair but this prevents me from editing the initial settings afterward.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to enable 'Advanced' particle settings. Then a tab for the particle rotation will show up. Enable it and set 'Phase' and 'Random to 1:
[image]

Now the particles will be rotated randomly:
[image]

By default the objects will be pointing up with their y-axis and also rotate around that axis. You can play around with the 'Initail Orientation' setting and its random value to get different rotation behavior.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking to do - thank you for the clear and concise answer!